# Moving close to the Shul

Tags: halacha, shabbat, synagogue, travel

How close to the shul would a Rabbi generally require congregants or a prospective convert to move (in kilometers please!)?

Comment: "Walking distance".  That'll vary with the individual.  Me?  A mile is no problem.  Grandma?  Closer.

Comment: I second @MonicaCellio. A congregant won't generally be required by his or her rabbi to be "close" to Shul. But a prospective convert (p.c.) will likely be required to do several things to show commitment, one of which is to move to within "walking distance" (a subjective distance) to a Shul. A pickier rabbi might recommend that a p.c. find a home deeply embedded in the community (eg., if the Shul is on the edge of the community and a p.c. finds a house 6 blocks away surrounded by Jewish neighbors and another 3 blocks away outside the neighborhood, the rabbi might recommend the first one).

Comment: You should also take *techum* into consideration. Depending on local considerations, you could live a mile away but still be prohibited from walking to the synagogue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, what's reasonably walkable? Probably about 2 kilometers or so.

Another significant factor -- if the synagogue's neighborhood has an eruv, it's reasonable for a rabbi to expect people to move within the eruv -- it will be far easier to observe shabbos if you can carry in the neighborhood (especially if most of the locals are used to doing so). Take [Pittsburgh's eruv](https://sites.google.com/site/pittsburgheruv/eruv-map), for instance. You could find points within a 2-km radius of the synagogue that are outside of the eruv.

Most eruv maps are up online these days, so search around a bit (or ask) and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Or, for examples near Mahalia's declared location: http://eruv.org.za/

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I found that site on Google. The OU has an eruv map on their site which I checked out as well.

Comment: @MahaliaSamuels, so did I, naturally :)